# What could be a single term (for use in a website) to refer to a community that encompasses students groups, academic institutes & recruiters?

Tags: website-design, buttons, copywriting, social-media, community

I need a simple term that I could use in website's main navigation bar to refer to community encompassing academic groups, academic institutes & recruiters.

The target page is supposed to contain all users of the site under one head. The users emcompass students, colleges and recruiters.

I was thinking of using something similar to 'Communities' for this purpose.

Comment: I dont think it is very appropriate, also it is not very easy to guess

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question and try http://english.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Academia? (assuming that the recruiters work in the same field too)

Comment: @Marielle: `Academia` does not encompass recruiters(which can be from any field besides education)

Comment: Could you tell us the purpose of this website or page? Is it to connect the students and the recruiters if so you could go for something like Career fair participants (I know its not one word but still). You could also do Recruiters and Recruits.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for something like **Educational** or **Educational industry**.

Yes, it's fairly vague, but the list that you want it to encompass is in itself broad, so the term will be as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would submit that there isn't ONE label that you can put on this group because, they are in fact separate. Recruiters are partners to the university/college/school community but they are not part of it.

You can't pull them into the Educational Industry because they are part of Industry and not Education - with the exception of recruiters who work within Education.

For me, you are trying to architect a group that just doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, to me it sounds like we have "Academia" and "Recruiters," I don't think they can be mixed in any direct way.

Answer (score 1):

They are split between Academia and Recruiters. They sound pretty mutually exclusive.

On a different note, why are you trying to amalgamate different personas into one ? Sounds like a client decision IMHO?

Answer (score 1):

What about approaching it from the activity and context rather than the group type? What will these people do with your site? Maybe that was the reason to lump them together in the first place? You may find the answer by rephrasing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Given the Recruiters it sounds like **Networks** would be the most appropriate. Then all those academics and students can do some networking with those recruiters.